# SVN reports merge conflict where there is no conflict

Tags: svn

When I undo a commit using `svn merge -c -62255`, I get the following merge conflict:

```
<<<<<<< .working
                public boolean foo() {
                        return true;
                }
||||||| .merge-left.r62255
                public boolean foo() {
                        return true;
                }
=======
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r62254
```

How is that a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a change in whitespace in a revision after 62255. In other words, after I added that function, someone removed a space from the end of the last line, which is of course hard to notice in a diff.